# Do affinities preserve convexity?

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

I wonder if an affine transformation between real affine spaces (defined as in [Characterisation of affine transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795035/characterisation-of-affine-transformations) ) preserves convexity.

I recall that a subset of a real affine space is convex if, for every two its points A and B, it contains the point A+k(B-A) for every k in [0,1] (real line interval). A function between affine spaces preserves convexity if the image of every convex subset of the domain is convex (in the codomain).

Comment: I suggest you try to prove this yourself

Comment: I have indeed tried. I consider a convex subset S of the domain and two its points A and B. I have to find, for every k in [0,1], a point C of the domain such that f(C)= f(A)+k(f(B)-f(A)). But how do I find that C?

Comment: Try rewriting the right hand side as $(1-k)f(A) + k f(B)$. That strongly suggests a comparison with $f( (1-k)A + k B)$, because $(1-k)A + kB$ is a point on the line segment between $A$ and $B$. (When $k = 0$ it's $A$; when $k = 1$, it's $B$. For values of $k$ between $0$ and $1$, it's between them.

Comment: @JohnHughes I can't interpret your hint since in this context + involves either two vectors (in the underlying vector space) or a point of the affine space and a vector of the vector space. Instead, your suggestion would make it a binary operation over the points of the affine space.

Comment: I had myself made a similar mistake in the question. I've just fixed it.

Comment: Use the definition of an affine map.

Comment: Can you prove that the image of a convex set under a linear transformation is convex? Once you have that apply the definition of an affine map directly for the full result.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I managed to prove the preservation of (vector spaces subsets) convexity under vector spaces homomorphisms. I didn't guess how to use it directly to prove the desired statement, but then I've finally found a direct proof. I thank you for the suggestion; if you (or Deane ) wish to submit an answer, I'd give you the placet. I'd also suggest your visit to the open question I linked above.

Comment: An "affine combination", $aP + bQ$, where $a + b = 1$ is easy to define in an affine space. You let $v = Q - P$, and then take $P + bv$. The nice thing about this rewritten form is that it suggests things like that in my comment, namely that $f(A) + kf(B)$ *might* actually be $f( (1-k)A + k B)$..which reinterprets to $f(A + k(B-A))$. In the language of your linked question, this is $f(A) + kg(B-A)$, where $g$ is the associated linear transformation. Thinking in terms of affine combinations can be fairly useful in general, but YMMV. (TBH, I didn't know what was your definition of affine space.)